# Groovy:XML structure translation

Tags: xml, groovy

**Input XML**

```
<ClientInformation>
<FirstName>Ram</FirstName>
<LastName>Shah</LastName>
<MiddleName></MiddleName>
<DateOfBirth>01/01/1972</DateOfBirth>
<TaxIdentification>12346</TaxIdentification>
<RelationshipToInsuredCT>Spouse</RelationshipToInsuredCT>
<RelationshipToEmployeeCT>Spouse</RelationshipToEmployeeCT>
<RoleTypeCT>Insured</RoleTypeCT>
</ClientInformation>
```

**Output XML**

```
<ContractClientVO>
 <ConstantElement1></ConstantElement1>
 <ConstantElement2></ConstantElement2>
 <RelationshipToInsuredCT>Spouse</RelationshipToInsuredCT>
 <RelationshipToEmployeeCT>Spouse</RelationshipToEmployeeCT>
 <ClientRoleVO>
  <ClientRoleConstantElement1></ClientRoleConstantElement1>
  <RoleTypeCT>Insured</RoleTypeCT>
  <ClientDetailVO>
   <FirstName>Ram</FirstName>
    <LastName>Shah</LastName>
    <MiddleName></MiddleName>
    <DateOfBirth>01/01/1972</DateOfBirth>
    <TaxIdentification>12346</TaxIdentification>
  </ClientDetailVO>
 <ClientRoleVO>
</ContractClientVO>
```

**XML for Mapping Reference**

```
<ClientInformation>
    <ContractClientVO>
     <AssignmentReasonCT></AssignmentReasonCT>
     <Associated></Associated>
     <AuthorizedSignatureCT></AuthorizedSignatureCT>
     <ClassCT></ClassCT>
     <RelationshipToInsuredCT></RelationshipToInsuredCT>
     <RelationshipToEmployeeCT></RelationshipToEmployeeCT>
     <ClientRoleVO>
      <AgentFK></AgentFK>
      <Associated></Associated>
      <RoleTypeCT></RoleTypeCT>
      <ClientDetailVO>
        <address></address>
        <city></city>
        <state></state>
        <Amount></Amount>
        <CountryTypeCT></CountryTypeCT>
        <AmountOfInsurance></AmountOfInsurance>
        <FirstName></FirstName>
        <LastName></LastName>
        <TaxIdentification></TaxIdentification>
     </ClientDetailVO>
   </ClientRoleVO>
  </ContractClientVO>
 </ClientInformation>
```

So third xml is for reference. It helps to define the structure of output xml.
Is there a out of the box solution from Groovy for this kind of problem? Or I have go by each `input xml` element and validate it with `reference xml`.

Comment: Xslt would seem to be the way forward here?

Comment: I also have no idea how listing 3 relates to listing 1 or 2

Comment: Listing 3 has intermediate elements. Listing 1 is more of a flat xml.Listing 3 tells about the structure of the xml. For example.`<FirstName>` will come under `<ClientDetailVO>`

Comment: Yeah, I'd look into xslt.  Xslt was designed to transform one XML document into another

Comment: Added an answer with some example xslt and the code to run the transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, given this xml:

```
<Clients>
    <ClientInformation>
        <FirstName>Ram</FirstName>
        <LastName>Shah</LastName>
        <MiddleName></MiddleName>
        <DateOfBirth>01/01/1972</DateOfBirth>
        <TaxIdentification>12346</TaxIdentification>
        <RelationshipToInsuredCT>Spouse</RelationshipToInsuredCT>
        <RelationshipToEmployeeCT>Spouse</RelationshipToEmployeeCT>
        <RoleTypeCT>Insured</RoleTypeCT>
    </ClientInformation>
</Clients>
```

You can use this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Output>
            <xsl:for-each select="Clients/ClientInformation">
                <ContractClientVO>
                    <ConstantElement1></ConstantElement1>
                    <ConstantElement2></ConstantElement2>
                    <RelationshipToInsuredCT><xsl:value-of select="RelationshipToInsuredCT"/></RelationshipToInsuredCT>
                    <RelationshipToEmployeeCT><xsl:value-of select="RelationshipToEmployeeCT"/></RelationshipToEmployeeCT>
                    <ClientRoleVO>
                        <ClientRoleConstantElement1></ClientRoleConstantElement1>
                        <RoleTypeCT><xsl:value-of select="RoleTypeCT"/></RoleTypeCT>
                        <ClientDetailVO>
                            <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/></FirstName>
                            <LastName><xsl:value-of select="LastName"/></LastName>
                            <MiddleName><xsl:value-of select="MiddleName"/></MiddleName>
                            <DateOfBirth><xsl:value-of select="DateOfBirth"/></DateOfBirth>
                            <TaxIdentification><xsl:value-of select="TaxIdentification"/></TaxIdentification>
                        </ClientDetailVO>
                    </ClientRoleVO>
                </ContractClientVO>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To generate:

```
<Output>
   <ContractClientVO>
      <ConstantElement1 />
      <ConstantElement2 />
      <RelationshipToInsuredCT>Spouse</RelationshipToInsuredCT>
      <RelationshipToEmployeeCT>Spouse</RelationshipToEmployeeCT>
      <ClientRoleVO>
         <ClientRoleConstantElement1 />
         <RoleTypeCT>Insured</RoleTypeCT>
         <ClientDetailVO>
            <FirstName>Ram</FirstName>
            <LastName>Shah</LastName>
            <MiddleName />
            <DateOfBirth>01/01/1972</DateOfBirth>
            <TaxIdentification>12346</TaxIdentification>
         </ClientDetailVO>
      </ClientRoleVO>
   </ContractClientVO>
</Output>
```

The groovy to transform the xml would be (assuming the xml is in a String called `xml` and the xsl is in a String called `xsl`):

```
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource

def w = new StringWriter()
TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                  .newTransformer( new StreamSource( new StringReader( xsl ) ) )
                  .transform( new StreamSource( new StringReader( xml ) ),
                  new StreamResult( w ) )
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( w.toString() )
```

Comment: How about the reverse translation?

Comment: You'd need to simply write some xsl similar to above